# Crosswalk Cordova - js alert shows block characters on Chinese interface android

Tags: android, cordova, android-alertdialog, crosswalk-runtime

I have a Phonegap Android app with barcode reader which I migrated to Crosswalk using the beta version, and now my alert dialog shows strange blocks instead of latin characters, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

This should show the following text instead, which it did on the pure Phonegap version :

```
Alert
We got a barcode
Result: 6927xxxxxxxxxxx
Format: EAN_13
Cancelled: false
```

Specs:

- Chinese Hong Kong
- LG G3 Android 4.4
- ARM
- Crosswalk Beta 10

I'm suspecting it's some sort of encoding/language issue because I've got Chinese set as my system language on the phone.

**Please notice that I did not censor the text, nor they are Chinese characters.** The text which it should display is in my code block.

Please comment if more information is needed !

Comment: You should try use `navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])` http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html

Comment: I'm getting this with US English keyboard. on API 19 & 22 (64 bit).

Comment: I've updated https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3187

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will work but just give it a shot. Remove the crosswalk plugin and then add it again. Similar issue was caused for my apache ionic framework application, the above method worked for me. Try it.